# Mysql : ORDER BY Twice

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-order-by

**EDITED :**
I need users to be ordered by their global progression [order by avg(progression) DESC] and the lines of details orderd by progression.

**Example** :

```
USER 1 campaign 1 progression 100 
USER 1 campaign 2 progression 100
USER 2 campaign 1 progression 95 
USER 2 campaign 2 progression 80
USER 3 campaign 1 progression 70 
USER 3 campaign 2 progression 25
```

I run the following query:

```
SELECT p.usersid, p.current_campaign, p.campaign_progression
FROM progression_campagne p 
JOIN USER u ON  p.usersid=u.id AND u.organismsid=10 
GROUP BY p.usersid, p.current_campaign
ORDER BY p.usersid DESC,p.campaign_progression DESC;
```

To get result like this :

[image]

But I got the following result:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: What is wrong with your output please add details

Comment: In your result,  why should user 19 be under user 66? and why should 64 be under 63?

Comment: Can you please show your table's data?

Comment: This looks like you want have 2 groups those which have progression values and those which do not and you want to sort those which do in the userid order by sum of total progression in descending order and those which do not in ascending order

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an average column and use this as the first sort column

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(user int, campaign int , progression int);
insert into t values
(1 , 1 , 100) ,
(1 , 2 , 100),
(2 , 1 , 95 ),
(2 , 2 , 80),
(3 , 1 , 70 ),
(3 , 2 , 25);

select user,campaign, progression, (select avg(t1.progression) from t t1 where t1.user = t.user group by t1.user) average
from t
order by average desc,user desc,progression desc;

+------+----------+-------------+----------+
| user | campaign | progression | average  |
+------+----------+-------------+----------+
|    1 |        1 |         100 | 100.0000 |
|    1 |        2 |         100 | 100.0000 |
|    2 |        1 |          95 |  87.5000 |
|    2 |        2 |          80 |  87.5000 |
|    3 |        1 |          70 |  47.5000 |
|    3 |        2 |          25 |  47.5000 |
+------+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: thank you for your great response, i'm gonna need your help in translating it to HQL (Hibernate Query langage) please.

Comment: Never used HQL but I would guess that it would be much the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.